# Can I reinstall Windows 10 without erasing all my data?

Tags: windows-10, reinstall

I switched my Intel-based Windows 10 box to an AMD-based processor and motherboard. It’s running, but keeps getting kernel crashes, and I’m considering re-installing Windows. Can I do that without deleting my data, or would it be better to back the whole thing up first, erase the hard drive, and do a fresh installation?

Comment: You would have to use an imaging program that supports restoring images to dissimilar hardware.  So it is possible to transfer the installation.  The license possibly is another story all together

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound, but if this were me (it kind of has been), I would back everything up, reinstall Windows from the Microsoft Media Creation link, Keep Nothing. Now try to activate Windows and if issues, contact licensing support. When all is running, do driver updates and test for crashing. Then restore your data. This is a way to keep your license.

Comment: Provided the license is a retail license activation won’t be a problem.  The problem a lot of websites sell OEM licenses and they are cheaper than the retail license so lots of people end up buying a OEM license despite it not actually being an OEM device